# cannot parse JSON in response

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, ionic-framework

Problem State: I calling post request using javaScript and in response i am expecting array of dictionary in JSON Format. here is my code.

```
let jsonData = JSON.stringify(params)
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, jsonData , this.options)
.map(res => res.json()) 
.subscribe( data => {

    console.log(data);
    if (data != null){
      this.data = data

    }else{
      console.log(' Data is null')
    }
  },

   () => console.log('Call Complete')

 );
```

I am get this error:

**-  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.**

even like that i added this header into post request.

```
this.myheader = new Headers({
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS, PUT',
```

});

How can I get rid off it.. Thanks

Comment: `post` is likely to be async but your code seems to treat it as if it is a sync method. I bet that's where your problem lies.

Comment: users: [] = {};
push your response into this,
and check on data length.